# Is it possible to make synthetic olfactory receptors?

Tags: human-biology, cell-biology, receptor, peripheral-nervous-system

Are there any electronic engineering technologies that allow people to make synthetic olfactory receptor that generate electrical impulses when exposed to certain proteins or molecules? If not, what are the primary challenges of creating such a device?

Comment: Have you performed any prior research - I'm asking, because the question is really broad. Do you mean electronic (macro)devices? or artificially bio-engineered proteins, or cells of some kind?

Comment: @AliceD At this point in time, I am interested in any detecting technology that can be customized to detect specific compounds similar to olfactory receptors. I have done some research, but I have not found anything that would be able to link into electronics systems and be reusable like our own nerves. I have done some research (my background is engineering), but it took me a good deal of time to even find anyone who could describe in detail how the olfactory receptors work to detect multiple smells.

Comment: Thanks for that, I've edited your post a little bit to clarify that point. and to hat end do you need this technology? For a sensorineural implant to replace the lost sense of olfaction (a biocompatible 'bionic nose')? Or is it more for some kind of computerized detection system that can, and should operate out of the body and 'simply' detect different odors?

Comment: My gut reaction is that this feels outside of Biology per se; there are certainly chemical 
"sniffers" of a variety of types - can you explain how your question necessarily relates to biology per se? As far as how olfactory receptors work, have you tried introductory-level neuroscience textbooks? It's pretty common for them to have at least a chapter on olfaction.

Comment: Depending on just what you mean by "olfactory receptor", this might be an absolutely trivial question.  Ckips that can "smell" for instance carbon monoxide are readily available for a couple of bucks.  Others can smell CO2, alcohol, LPG, the oxygen in your car's exhaust, explosives...

Comment: @AliceD - So to clarify my purpose that isn't necessarily pertinent to the question itself: It seems like being able to create a synthetic and readily reusable smelling device that is as powerful as that of a dogs would be a world changing invention. In the medical field alone, there are numerous diseases which dogs have the ability to accurately smell and diagnose instantly. I posed this question to biologist as I thought the only way to create the wide range of detectors needed to get an accurate sensor would be to synthesize a large variety of proteins like our receptors.

Comment: @jamesqf- What is a Ckips? I can't seem to find any reference to such a thing...

Comment: You might be asking this questions because there has been reports in the news about dogs possibly being able to detect patients infected by COVID19. You can read similar reports every single time there is a new disease or new scary thing. Don't pay attention to it, it only tells you how much people like reading about dogs.

Comment: But to answer your question there is a bench of devices that can measure compounds in gases much more effectively than animals. For example photoionization (basically spectroscopy) or chemically. If you know what you want to detect. Usually you don't.